# I am new to android development. I am making my first app but I am getting an error:

Tags: android

Error: ' ' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergingException$Builder.build(MergingException.java:152)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RohO.png)

Comment: `ic_launcher_background 2.xml` has a space here `background 2`. Android resources files should obey [a-z0-9_] regular expression rule. Generally, It is a good idea to search the error code for well-known solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You named your icon: ic_launcher_background 2.xml
White spaces are not allowed as name of files. Try changing it to: ic_launcher_background_2.xml

Hope this helped.